# Com ports identification

Tags: 13.10, ham-radio

I am a relative new user with Ubuntu 13.10 and I have always been puzzled in trying to identify Com ports. On Windows systems it is an easy task but I have not mastered it on Ubuntu.

I have 3 USB to serial devices plugged into my computer and I need to know specifics about them and how to changed their parameters. My Ham radio software CRQLOG needs this information.

Thanks
Richard, KC8RP

Answer (score 1):

In linux communication ports are files.

If you use USB to serial adapters, the first one will be /dev/ttyUSB0 the second one /dev/ttyUSB1 etc.

You can see them by looking in /dev

Jean-Marie VE2AEY